# How to disable sound from an app

Tags: 4.1-jelly-bean, audio

I have got a game I play (*The Simpsons Tapped Out*) that is based on time. (For example every 5 hours I get a coin).

But every time something is completed (like a quest) I hear from the speakers something like ("yeaho work is done!")

I would like to disable that sound, but there is no setting for it within the game.

Because when I am working I want to hear when someone is calling, not when the app is done doing something.

Is there a way to disable the sound of one app?

Or is there a setting in my phone that can disable that sound?

I am using Android 4.1.2 on an LG Optimus L5.

Comment: Not a real solution, but at least a work-around: Put all volume sliders to 0, except for alerts and ringers (plus maybe system; experiment a little). With some luck, the app is using either the multimedia or at least notification channel, and thus would be silenced – while your alerts and incoming calls would still be "announced".

Comment: I have tried that, but when i put up the volume slider of calls, it will automaticly put up the volume of the game

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are several possibilities:

- manually setting all volumes to 0, except for those channels you want to keep (e.g. alerts, notifications, system). Issue: on some devices/systems some channels seem to be "locked together", so as soon as e.g. volume for calls is increased, some other slider increases automatically along. An app like [Audio Control](http://www.appbrain.com/app/com.matthew.rice.volume.master.lite) might help on that.
- same thing, but use some automation tool (e.g. [tasker](/questions/tagged/tasker)). This might work-around the slider-lock.
- disabling notifications from the app (might not work if the app doesn't count that as "notification")
- if root access is available: replace/remove the corresponding sound file (credits go [to Dan](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/12467531#12467531) for this)
- using a helper like [App Override](http://www.xda-developers.com/android/personalized-settings-for-individual-apps-with-app-override/). Unfortunately this is no longer available on *Google Play*, so I linked to the original thread on XDA.

Comment: So what u did was i went to setting/applications and selected my game, and clicked on disable "reports", should that work?

Comment: Also, app override is an app for rooted devices only, and its not rooted, and setting all volues to 0 wont work

Comment: 1) I never tried, don't have any use for that. 2) sorry for that: in my list, it was in the "normal" section (not in the "root" section); I probably have misplaced it. As it was removed from *Play*, I couldn't cross-check there. 3) you would set the game app to "silent mode" with *App Override*, not manipulating the sliders. As for *Tasker*, there was a volumes plugin AFAIR. But you could try [Audio Control](http://www.appbrain.com/app/com.matthew.rice.volume.master.lite), which separates the sliders (according to its description).

Answer (score 7):

If you happen to be on a Samsung phone, there is an app called "[Sound Assistant](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.samsung.android.soundassistant&hl=en_CA)" which is excellent - adding volume sliders for whatever individual apps you like.

They waste a lot of money and frustrate a lot of people customizing & bloating Android, but this *optional* app is great and should be mimicked by Google into base Android!

Comment: Found this in the Galaxy Store as well.  Thank you for pointing it out--it's perfect for my needs.

Comment: Yeah but you cant select any app to silence - like since the Android 12 update the Calculator now has key clicks that cannot be silenced and you cannot select it i the SoundAssistant